# Birt Eclipse, connecting to a SQLite database through ODBC? Do I need a specific JDBC driver for Birt to use?

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, jdbc, odbc, birt

I have been working on this for a while now and, unfortunately have little previous exposure to Birt as well as JDBC / ODBC. I've been searching and searching but can't conclusively figure out what I need for Birt to be able to connect to an SQLite database through ODBC.

I have setup the SQLit db on my windows machine to use ODBC. From here, however, I can't figure out, in the Birt Report Designer-> New data source-> JDBC data source what I am supposed to put in in order to access the DB.

Do I need a specific driver for this that I need to install to use as the "Driver Class"

Is the path to my ODBC / SQLite db the "Driver URL" field?

I would greatly appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [JDBC driver](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) specifically for SQLite, so you don't have to use a bridge.

The URL should be:

```
jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/my.db
```

The class is `org.sqlite.JDBC`.

Comment: thanks for the help, this should help save some of my sanity :) (spent the better part of a day trying to familiarize myself with all this stuff)

Answer (score 0):

As the initial answer points out, you can download the SQLite JDBC driver.  Once downloaded, you need to correctly deploy the JAR into BIRT so the driver will be available in the eclipse designer.  Put the JAR in:

```
<BIRT Install>\eclipse\plugins\com.actuate.data.oda.jdbc.drivers_<BIRT VERSION>
```

Once the JAR is there, re-start Eclipse/BIRT and you should be able to create a SQLite data source pretty easily.

Good Luck!