# Eclipse cannot load JDBC Driver class: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver?

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, eclipse-plugin, birt

I am working with the BIRT Report Design Feature that is built into eclipse.  I am using this to develop a report for an application we use at work.  In BIRT, I added a data source which would be the database that I want to pull my data from.  The problem occurs whenever I try to access Data Sets to write my query that will specify the data that I want to pull in.  When I try to do this I get an error:

> cannot load JDBC Driver class: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Does anyone know if I need to get certain .jar file and where to put it?  Or do I need to download a special driver or plugin or what exactly do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Birt Eclipse, connecting to a SQLite database through ODBC? Do I need a specific JDBC driver for Birt to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445974/birt-eclipse-connecting-to-a-sqlite-database-through-odbc-do-i-need-a-specific)

Comment: It is the same question, but a different driver. You can download it from http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded the .jar file and when you go to add a Data Source there is a manage driver button you must click and add the .jar file that was downloaded from sourceforge.  After I did this I no longer got the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cannot load JDBC Driver class: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`

is basically because your application has dependency on `jtds.jar` which is unavailable in the classpath so first download the jar from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.3.1) and add it to the classpath.

[This is where](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/install.php) you may want to get start with